# Custom fill gradient yields error in self$oob(x, range = limits) : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot using `ggplot` with a custom fill gradient. I wanted to set limits on the fill gradient, and use squish parameter on oob to set limits to the fill gradient, but I end up getting the error: `Error in self$oob(x, range = limits) : attempt to apply non-function.` The error should be able to be reproduced with the code below:

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame("name" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"),
                  "percent" = c(0, 5, 10, 11, 22, 25, 30, 80),
                  "differential" = c(-20, -10, -5, 5, 10, 22, 30, 50))
# Plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(percent, differential, fill = differential))+
    geom_point(shape = 21, colour = "black")+
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#C93135",
                        high = "#1375B7",
                        mid = "grey90",
                        midpoint = 0,
                        aesthetics = "fill",
                        limits = c(-30,30),
                        oob = squish(x=df$differential,
                                     range=c(-30,30)))
p
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: ```oob = squish``` should suffice

Comment: Great! Thank you @P.Chakytei . This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by P.Chakytei, I just needed to use `oob = squish` without all the extra parameters.